# In log4net, how can I call Config.XmlConfigurator only once for a solution?

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm just getting started with log4net.  To read the XML configuration file, it is my understanding that you have to place the following in the AssemblyInfo file of your project:

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile:="Log4net.Config", Watch:=True)>
```

I have a solution with several projects, and it seems that I have to put this statement in every AssemblyInfo file in the solution (one for each project).  I tried just putting the statement in the Startup project's AssemblyInfo, but logging calls in other projects won't work.  I have to include the statement in every project that makes logging calls.

1)  Is there a way to make the call to Config.XmlConfigurator in one place, one time for an entire solution?

2)  What causes the behavior I'm seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use static constructor in class that will be referenced by all assemblies? If they are in single app domain than it will be called exactly once.

Comment: This may be the route I take.  I had thought about having a bootstrapper class that would do things like this at startup, but right now the only thing that would be in it would be this call, so I thought I would try the AssemblyInfo approach first.

Comment: Ended up going this route and creating a static bootstrapper class that is called at startup to initialize log4net (and anything else the app needs).

Answer (score 3):

You should place this in the assembly who "host" your solution. In a console/winform/wpf application in the assembly who compile to the ".exe", in a web application I usually call explicitly `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` in the Application-Start event.

Comment: I thought this should work too, but it doesn't, which led me to ask the question.  I'm using Winforms.  If I only put the XmlConfigurator call in the Winforms project's AssemblyInfo, then none of the other projects (class libraries) are able to log.

Comment: Try to explicitly call XmlConfigurator.Configure() even in winform app. I don't remember well, but I think there is some issue with the attrib.